# How can I automate running a PowerShell script that prompts UI for choice?

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a powershell script p1.ps1 that looks like this (not exactly, but this would do as an example):

```
$yes = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Yes", "Do the action."
$no = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&No", "Exit."
$options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($yes, $no)
$result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 1)
```

How can I write another script p2.ps1, that will run the first one (p1.ps1) and provide it with an answer to the prompt, so that p2.ps1 executes with no questions asked?

I have tried:

```
echo y | p1.ps1
```

but it does not do the trick.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$host.ui.PromptForChoice()` is interacting with the host, not with the output stream from a pipeline. I'm not aware of a way to automate host prompts.

A cleaner solution would be adding a `-Force` switch to `p1.ps1`:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [switch]$Force = $false
)
```

and making that switch override the prompt:

```
if (-not $Force) {
  $yes = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription ...
  $no  = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription ...
  $options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($yes, $no)
  $result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 1)
} else {
  $result = 0
}
```

That way the prompt won't be displayed when you run the script like this:

```
./p1.ps1 -Force
```

Comment: And if he needs to be able to force another result value, he could add a ParameterSet that accepts `-Force` and other parameters to define the values the prompt would normally give. :)

Comment: Well this is definitely a backup option if I don't manage to provide an answer to the script. I would like to solve it properly because I would like to automate test that will exercise all answers (Yes, No, Help, FooBar).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you are spawning the script, powershell sendkeys could do the trick.

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("Y")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")
```

Caveats, it won't work if script is run hidden as we cannot sendkeys to invisible windows.  We may need to add a line or two setting Focus to the first script window in the case it does not already have focus when we send the "Y + ENTER" commands.

Comment: Actually, because I run it with powershell.exe there is no window, but "command line" Y/N question.

Comment: To change focus use `[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic")
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("Test.ps1 - Notepad")`  ref: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731008.aspx